# Sinatra app throws error when not using Shotgun

Tags: ruby, sinatra, shotgun

**Context:** I have a simple Sinatra app: `app.rb` is at the root of my project's directory, and a `views/` directory sits at the same level as `app.rb`.

When I run my app with `ruby app.rb`, it throws an error in which it appears that Sinatra doesn't know where the `views/` directory is:

```
Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
/{Two Directories Above Project Root}/views/admin.erb
```

For some reason, Sinatra seems to think the root of my project is two levels above where it actually is, and I can't figure out why. When I set the views folder explicitly, this error goes away, but other aspects of my application breaks because my app doesn't appear to know where it lives.

When I run the app with `shotgun`, I don't get this error. I'm using shotgun for now, so it's not a big deal. I'm just trying to nail down why this behavior is occurring.

Comment: What's the current layout of your project? If you have the `tree` command, its output would be useful.